# Replace Current controlled Voltage Source Converter with Rectifier Diodes in ELC?

Tags: control, rectifier, converter, inductance, load

In [this](http://www.scirp.org/journal/PaperDownload.aspx?FileName=JEMAA20110400006_71214505.pdf&paperID=4625) paper an Electronic Load Controller (ELC) for two (2) parallel generators is designed. I wish to omit the second generator and hope for simplification.

**Now two questions arose:** (while I believe I get the point that this is how the reactive power is controlled while functioning as a normal recitfier for active power control, i.e. frequency control)

1. Inductance for high power rating are very expensive - why exactly do we find 1-Generator 1-Phase designs where the inductances are omitted? Or rather: Why do we need this inductance for filtering, buffering of reactive power here in the mentioned ELC design? Is it related to the 2-generator configuration? Is it because of the 3 phases? Is it possible to omit or replace their function?
2. The working principle of the PWM dump loading is that we rectify the power the generators produce and no load currently needs. This task is solved by a Voltage Source Converter (VSC). The question arises if it is possible to go with Rectifier Diodes instead as simplification?

@2. Currently I can't see why not other than that some special power component is being controlled by this VSC or probably because diodes are not suitable for 5..20kW power range?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

1. It's easily dismissed that the VSC also functions as an inverter, thus the inductances not only buffer reactive power but also function as filter for cancelling undesired harmonics.
2. If no voltage balancing across all the three phases is required, one directional rectifier diodes do the job but it is risky! Generators might get destroyed by load unbalance.

The current requirements for the inductances can be chosen similar to the output filter design of high power DC -> AC inverters.